# ERRORS ITMS-9000 Application publishing error

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode5

Every time i try uploading my app to the app store it gives me this error. Please help, i thank everyone who answers in advance.

The error is:

ERROR ITMS-9000: "Storyboard file 'Main_iPhone - ipad.storyboardc' was no found. Please ensure the specified file is included in the bundle with any required device modifiers appended to the filename."

(I can't post a picture because my reputation is not too high, i only  started a couple of days ago)